# Can I download copy of all discussions on Facebook that I've taken part in?

Tags: facebook, comments, export

I know it's possible to [download a copy of my Facebook data](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/131112897028467?rdrhc), but many comments made on discussion threads are quite irrelevant without the proper context of the discussion. I do have access to seeing the data via the normal Facebook UI but I would like to keep a private copy of it for future reference.

Is there a way to **download a copy of all comments posted by anyone on *every item* to which I also posted a comment** (preferably including the amount of likes on each of the comments, and even further the identity of the persons who liked them, though that is mostly irrelevant)?

Comment: The only way I'm aware of is a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of doing this that I can think of is to open the page in chrome and save it as PDF that way you have a record of the conversation and its also searchable. 
If you dont use chrome you could also use a pdf conversion tool like [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com)

Comment: Sorry, my question was a bit unclear - I would want a copy of *all* of the discussions I've participated in. I edited the question to make this more clear.